# How to use redux time travel and bind it to ctrl + z and ctrl + shift + z keybinds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an editor application that ads / changes / removes different views through redux state and I thought that it could be something really useful if I can implement ctrl+z and ctrl+shift+z with redux time travel as it will mean better user experience in cases where users remove element by mistake.

I was trying to read up on redux time travel, but everything related to it lead me to devtools articles, hence I wanted to see if you guys know of any good sources or can show examples that implement this feature?

My main issue is figuring out the logic after capturing key events.

Comment: Are you having trouble capturing keyboard input or implementing time travel?

Comment: @Mathletics implementing time travel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep track on user's history you may allocate an array inside your store and allow each action to get into otherwise you may use [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for a more persistent state.
On way or another I wrote down a fairly simple example with an "undo / CTRL+Z" listener:

```
const rnd = (state = {
  num: 0,
  prev: []
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POPHISTORY':
      if (state.prev.length > 1) {
        state.num = state.prev[state.prev.length - 2];
        state.prev.splice(-1, 1);

      }
      return state;
        // Add a new number 
    case 'RND':
      const num = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            //push into the tracking array
      state.prev.push(num);
            //update the current number
      state.num = num;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// JSX
const Counter = ({state, onRnd}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>{state.num}</h2>
    <h2>Previous numbers count:
      {state.prev.length}</h2>
    <button onClick={onRnd}>New number</button>
  </div>
);

// Create the store
const {createStore} = Redux;
const store = createStore(rnd); // bind reducers

//Listen for CTRL+Z
function KeyPress(e) {
  const evtobj = window.event
    ? event
    : e
  if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
    store.dispatch({type: 'POPHISTORY'})
  }
}
//bind the listener
window.onkeydown = KeyPress;

//Create the renderer
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter state={store.getState()} onRnd={() => store.dispatch({type: 'RND'})}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
};
// Combine React and Redux
store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Store a stringified version of the redux store in localStorage with a middleware. That middleware listens for the key event when it fires it loads the last state from localstorage etc etc.